# selection not returning to original position

Tags: javascript, html

### Problem

So I tried to follow the answer here [How to select text range within a contenteditable div that has no child nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33658630/how-to-select-text-range-within-a-contenteditable-div-that-has-no-child-nodes) but it doesn't return to the position after the newly inserted `\t` after I hit the tab key.

### Desired behaviour

E.g | = cursor

```
sen|tence

*press tab*

sen\t|tence
```

Fiddle seems to run better: https://jsfiddle.net/hw4mps0k/4/

```js
function insertTab (event) {
  if (event.which === 9)
  {
   event.preventDefault()
      let td = event.target
      let text = td.innerText
      let selection = window.getSelection()
      let node = td.childNodes[0]
      let start = selection.anchorOffset
      let end = selection.focusOffset
      let remove = end - start

      let new_range = document.createRange()
      new_range.setStart(node, start)
      new_range.setEnd(node, start)
      new_range.collapse(start)

      text = text.split("")
      text.splice(start, remove, "\t")
      text = text.join("")
      td.innerText = text;
      console.log(text)

      selection.removeAllRanges()
      selection.addRange(new_range)
   td.focus()
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
 white-space: pre;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td contenteditable="true" onkeydown="insertTab(event)"></td>
  </tr>  
 </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: your start and end value are always the same. what do you want to split?

Comment: @Araz I want it so that when I press tab and a `\t` is inserted, the cursor goes after the `\t` spot.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is not the perfect solution, but here's what I came up with:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* external.js */
var doc, htm, bod, M, I, old = onload; // for use on other loads
onload = function(){
if(old)old(); // change old var name if using technique on other pages
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; 
M = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
I('f').onsubmit = function(e){
  // do all your submission stuff here
  return false;
}
var et = I('edit');
et.onkeydown = function(e){
  var tab = false;
  if(e.key && e.key === 'Tab'){
    tab = true;
  }
  else{
    var k = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(k === 9)tab = true;
  }
  if(tab){
    this.value = this.value+'\t'; this.focus(); 
    return false;
  }  
}
}// end load
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
body{
  background:#000; overflow-y:scroll;
}
.main{
  width:940px; background:#ccc; padding:20px; margin:0 auto;
}
#edit{
  width:50px; height:50px; background:#fff; border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <form id='f'>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><input id='edit' type='text' value='' /></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody> 
      </table>    
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the tab is seen as white space.

Comment: If you type something, and try to tab in the middle of a word, nothing happens. Also the cursor disappears after tabbing

Comment: Works in Firefox. Are you sure your word isn't longer than the box? Hit `a` then tab then `b` and get back to me.

Comment: not working in chrome. Would like a Chorme + Firefox solution at a minimum.